# How to Append image to div, and fade image in over 1 second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to append an image to my div "gamecol", but I want to fade-in, not just appear immediately. Do I need to write a JavaScript function, or is there a method that I can use with css? Thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "./images/tbltop.jpg";
img.id = "gameboard"
var gamecol = document.getElementById("gamecol");
gamecol.appendChild(img)
```

```html
<div class="col-8" id="gamecol" style="padding:0"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with css, depending on the functionality you want, of course.
If you want it to fade in when the image enters to the screen view, you'll need javascipt.
If not, you only need to tell that, when the item is appended, you use CSS 3 animations to make it appear.
It could look like this:

```
.game-img
{
animation: fadein 1s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with CSS3 properties of **@keyframes(animation)**. I'm appending same image with help of **setTimeout** function for checking **fadein** effect. So it's working and easy to use.

```js
function TwoImages(){ 
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbpv.jpg";
  img.id = "gameboard";
  var gamecol = document.getElementById("gamecol");
  gamecol.appendChild(img)
}
TwoImages();

setTimeout(function(){
  TwoImages();
},2500);
```

```css
.fade-in img{
  animation: fadein 1s linear;
}  
@keyframes fadein {
  0% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<div id="gamecol" class="fade-in"></div>
```